# Plot graph and calculate average from the same range ignoring non numeric data (not plotting zeros!) in excel

Tags: excel, plot

Excel graph will not plot null cells and NA() (#N/A). Blank cells (="") for some odd unknown reason will plot as zeros! On the other hand, AVERAGE ignores both, null and blank cells! It does not consider blank as zeros! Which is the expected right behavior!

Graph:

- Ignore: null,  =NA() (#N/A)
- Plot as zero: blank (="")    // WHY  Microsoft? Why!!!??

AVERAGE(), or any other formula:

- Ignore: null or blank ("")
- Error: =NA() (#N/A), or any other non numeric data!

So, how to use the same column to plot a graph not plotting any non numeric and also calculate the average?

I know that I can just add an auxiliary column to plot, that checks if a value is blank, and replace with =NA(). But, in my case, that will require a lot of auxiliary columns, and I don't want that.

My data comes from formulas. So I can't have null/empty cells, only blank "".

Comment: All inclusive post on plotting empty values from Jon Peltier's blog. Post is called "Mind the Gap - charting empty cells" found [here](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/mind-the-gap-charting-empty-cells/). Take a look at that, try a few things, then post back with more specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

"A lot of auxiliary columns".. 1 is a lot? If data is in column B.

```
=IF(&B1 = "", NA(),&B1)
```

And drag it down.

## On topic for your problem :

There is an option, change it like that (French sorry):

[image]
[image]

Change it TO **the last choice** instead of **zeros** and it will link your data accordingly.

See [this for more information on these options](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/display-hidden-worksheet-data-and-empty-cells-in-a-chart-HA010048555.aspx).

## Edit 1

If you want to make an Average including **N/As**:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A5,"<>#N/A")
```

Comment: I know this option. But for excel, empty cell != "". For excel, empty is null, and you can't set a cell to null using a formula (why Microsoft why?). You need to delete the cell data. My data does have "" cells, so, this option is worthless for me. About the auxiliary column, I have a lot of columns. The hole reason of creating this thread is to not create an auxiliary column.

Comment: @Pedro77 How do you make a cell with ""? Doesn't it get emptied if ""(aka nothing) is entered in it?

Comment: My data comes from formulas, so, nothing will be "".

Comment: @Pedro77 I'm not sure I understand, you are saying that you don't have any cells that have `""`?? Why asking for all of this then? If your data comes from formulas, add to them my little formula that puts `N/A` instead of `""`.

Comment: No, just the opposite. I HAVE cells containing "". Also, how can I calculate AVERAGE with data containing N/A?

Comment: @Pedro77 You can do the average like this : `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A5,"<>#N/A")`. This is an average and ignores N/As.